# OSB Proxy service retry mechanism

Tags: oracle, jms, osb

I have created a JMS proxy service which fires on a message and routes the message to another JMS business service which puts the message into an out queue.

If the business service gives any error, I want the service to retry for 5 times. For this requirement I have set the retry count in routing options of the proxy service to 5. But, on third retry attempt, I want the proxy service to call a mail alert destination which sends a mail.

I am stuck at this point. Can anybody please help me in solving this ??

Comment: Please post your code and tell us what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Setting retry count as 'N' times in Business service will retry for 'N' times.

If error occurs even in 'N'th try, business service will return error to the route node.

Try calling the business service two times, splitting the retries like 3 and 2.

It would be better to use service callout and two stages

- Make call in first service callout with retry count as 3
- if it fails, make service call to mail alert destination in stage level error handler and resume
- Make call in second service callout with retry count as 2
- If first service callout returns success skip second service callout

This may also work

- try with retry count 3 in routing node
- if it fails, make service call to mail alert destination and call the business service with retry count 2
- If it also fails, handle the error in service level error handler